# MVC/PHP Where do I put code that make requests?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am currently trying to make a project using MVC (**with laravel**).

After searching, I didn't find a case that tells me exactly where (Controller or Model) I have to put my code that:

1. Get a webpage html source (with cUrl or something similar)
2. **Parses the html code** to take some informations on it
3. Put the parsed informations into a database

> I think it's the controller part but am I right ?

Here is how it works:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a CLI tool.

Comment: Depends on how the code should be executed. By command line, by web request, by cronjob, after something is created through a user action, ...

Comment: The code should be executed when the user visit a page like mywebsite.com/parseIt and then will parse the html of let's say www.site.com and put all informations I need into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the action is user triggered, you should either put the code into a controller or write your own parser class that lives in a service namespace or somewhere else. It is of course better to separate the code into separate classes than to put everything into your controller. Especially if the task could potentially also be called through another action than a web request.